# In API call If I click Submit button open 200code Success page other wise open Error Page 404 In ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, http-post

[Please find the attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKQ9y.png) Hi am newly learning ReactJS, I have written the entire code to create one API call using End User link if I do click on submit button open "Success 200Code page" otherwise open "404ERROR page" how to do this can you please explain anyone in below code for reference.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Regist extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            firstName:"",
            lastName:"",
            password:"",
            email:"",
            show:false
        }
    }
    submit(){
       
        let url = "http://3.7.199.212:3000/api/v0/authentication/register";
        let data=this.state;
        fetch(url,{
         method:'POST',
         headers:{
             "Content-Type":"application/json",
             "Accept":"application/json"
         } ,
         body:JSON.stringify(data)
         }).then((result)=>{
            result.json().then((res)=>{
                console.warn("res",res)
            })
         })
    }
    

    render(){
        return(
            <div>

                <input type = 'text' value= {this.state.firstName} name='firstName' placeholder="FirstName"
                 onChange={(data)=>{this.setState({firstName:data.target.value})}}/><br/>

                <input type = 'text' value= {this.state.lastName} name='lastName' placeholder="LastName"
                onChange={(data)=>{this.setState({lastName:data.target.value})}}/><br/>
                
                <input type = 'text' value= {this.state.password} name='password' placeholder="Password"
                onChange={(data)=>{this.setState({password:data.target.value})}}/><br/>

                <input type = 'text' value= {this.state.email} name='email' placeholder="Email"
                onChange={(data)=>{this.setState({email:data.target.value})}}/><br/>

                <button onClick={()=>{this.submit()}} >Submit</button>
              
                
        </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Regist;
```

Comment: Thank you for Reply, what actually my question for me is that I have to open new window like(pop-Up) in window show if Registration information Successful update then 200code come other wise if it is Already Existing information then show 406Error window when I submit my Registration Details

Answer (score 0):

First, welcome to the React world :)

You should bind `submit` function on constructor.
Add this inside the `constructor` function:

```
this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

After that,

```js
    submit(){
       
        let url = "http://3.7.199.212:3000/api/v0/authentication/register";
        let data=this.state;
        fetch(url,{
         method:'POST',
         headers:{
             "Content-Type":"application/json",
             "Accept":"application/json"
         } ,
         body:JSON.stringify(data)
         }).then((result)=>{
// If the request was success the code below will run
            result.json().then((res)=>{
                console.warn("res",res)
            })
         }).catch((error) => {
           // Otherwise this will run
           console.log(error)
            })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for Reply, what actually my question for me is that I have to open new window like(pop-Up) in window show if Registration information Successful update then 200code come other wise if it is Already Existing information then show 406Error window when I submit my Registration Details

Comment: May be this help https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-modal-component